# How can i catch server side error on flutter VideoPlayer?

Tags: flutter, vimeo, flutter-video-player

When trying to fetch the video with the Vimeo url,video_player and chewie player, I get the error

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403, null))
```

How can I print the image shown in the picture on the website instead of the error here?

```
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController _chewieController;
  double _aspectRatio = 16 / 9;
  TabController _tabController;

  void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
    _videoPlayerController =
        VideoPlayerController.network('myvideourl');
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
        allowedScreenSleep: false,
        allowFullScreen: true,
        deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ],
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
        aspectRatio: _aspectRatio,
        autoInitialize: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        showControls: true,
        errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              errorMessage,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          );
        });
    _chewieController.addListener(() {
      if (_chewieController.isFullScreen) {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        ]);
      } else {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ]);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff4fc1e9),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff3bafda),
          shadowColor: Color(0xff4a89dc),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              iconSize: 30.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {} //=> _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
              ),
          title: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/firm-logo.png",
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            height: 32,
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 5,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.5,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black26,
                          offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
                          blurRadius: 6.0),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Chewie(
                          controller: _chewieController,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

[image]

how can i catch this error on flutter app

Answer (score 2):

You could listen to errors like:

```
_controller.addListener(() {
 if (_controller.value.hasError) {
  print(_controller.value.errorDescription);
 }
});
```